# How to make Grow Light with LED?

Tags: flowering, support, grow-lamp, led

I made a LED setup with blue and red LED that is supposed to help me with indoor planting. I used total 4 LEDs (2 Red and 2 Blue) for one pot of Portolaca flowers. But I think it is not simulating the sunlight properly. How many LEDs am I supposed to use? How should I make the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find aquarium plants do well under LED. Maybe you need more light. My 36" fixture has 120 LEDs , including 10 blue , 10 red ( 2 different shades) and 2 green LEDs. Portulaca wants full sun light.